# RAID 0 for better MySQL performance

Tags: raid

I have initiated AWS high I/O instance. I will like to know if MySQL will perform better with RAID0. As per the following article...

http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2012/07/setting-up-raid0-in-ubuntu-12-04-in-aws-high-io/

```
With each instance you get 2x1TB of disk. 
In this tutorial I’ll be setting it up as a RAID0 to get a single 2TB disk which should deliver excellent performance.
```

I will like to know how much performance benefit will I get before trying to attempt it on my Instance.

Comment: It's totally dependant on your workload - of which you've provided no details.

Comment: Maybe I have not explained my question correctly. I need to know only the performance difference between RAID-0 and not using RAID at-all.

Comment: Still depends on workload. If the issue is latency then striping is not faster than a single disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about AWS instances and have never used them. RAID 0 gives better IO throughput because it stripes the data across the available disk.

There is a high risk of data loss when running RAID 0, therefore RAID 10 is a preferred alternative to it. Gives you the benefit of RAID 0 with redundancy (RAID 1) but requires 2x the number of disks.

[Wiki link explaining different types of RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Sameer that for a database application RAID 10 is best for performance and redundancy. Here is a another good link with a good chart on RAID and typical application associated.

http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/_common/compatibility/_education/raid_level_compar_wp.htm